# /usr/include won't work as a search path in xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, include-path, armadillo

I have installed the armadillo linear algebra library in /usr/include, so in xcode I added this dir into search path:

[image]

But xcode warned me that the armadillo file can't be found:

[image]

Then I copied the library files into /tmp/arma/, and added this into search path:

[image]

And miraculously everything turned ok:

[image]

I am really really confused now.

#### update

Just to confirm that armadillo is indeed in /usr/include:

```
kaiyin@kaiyins-mbp 07:30:09 | ~ =>
cd /usr/include/
kaiyin@kaiyins-mbp 07:30:20 | /usr/include =>
realpath armadillo
/usr/include/armadillo
kaiyin@kaiyins-mbp 07:30:25 | /usr/include =>
ll armadillo
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    20K Jun  1 04:44 armadillo
kaiyin@kaiyins-mbp 07:31:24 | /usr/include =>
file armadillo
armadillo: ASCII C++ program text
kaiyin@kaiyins-mbp 07:31:29 | /usr/include =>
head armadillo
// Copyright (C) 2008-2014 Conrad Sanderson
// Copyright (C) 2008-2014 NICTA (www.nicta.com.au)
//
// This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
// License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
// file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.


#ifndef ARMA_INCLUDES
#define ARMA_INCLUDES
kaiyin@kaiyins-mbp 07:31:32 | /usr/include =>
diff /tmp/arma/armadillo armadillo
kaiyin@kaiyins-mbp 07:32:11 | /usr/include =>
```

So it is sitting there and is the same as the one in /tmp/arma/

Comment: Are you missing one level, or is there really a file called `/usr/include/armadillo`?

Comment: Yes, there really is, see my edit to the question

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works in MAC. Actually it works fine in any Unix like system.

Comment: Please try to repeat what is stated in the question.